# Can't change values of function in its frame

Tags: python

In some educational purposes I want to work with function's frame from "inspect" module. I want to change the value of local var outer the function. I get the frame of this function and tried to change its value, but nothing is happened.

Why? Here's the simpled code:

```
from inspect import getouterframes, currentframe

def foo():
    frame_of_main = getouterframes(currentframe())
    frame_of_main[1][0].f_locals['var'] = 1
    print(frame_of_main[1][0].f_locals['var'])


def main():
    var = 1337
    foo()


main()
```

outputs: 1337

As you can see, the value of var in the frame hasn't changed. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

A frame's `f_locals` is the same dict returned by the `locals` function inside that frame. The [warning from the `locals` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) also applies to `f_locals`:

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by
>   the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks! So, do U know how to change it?